# How to track object positions in JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a trivia game similar to trivia crack using HTML CSS and vanilla JS. Currently, I have a pointer and I can make it spin but how do I track the pointer arrow to know where it lands on the window. If I can get the xPos and yPos, I can navigate to the correct category with just some if statements. This is the code for my pointer:

```
let pointerImg = document.querySelector(".pointerimg");
let number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);


pointerImg.addEventListener("click",()=> {
  pointerImg.style.transform = "rotate(" + number + "deg)";
  number += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how many segments there are on the shape, why not simply look at the resulting number you're passing into the `rotate` function, modulo 360 and work out which segment it's pointing at?

For example, assuming 5 segments and a rotation value of 4661 degrees:

```js
//Work out where in a 360 degree circle the arrow is pointing to knowing that it started at 0 and rotated 4661 degrees:
var deg = 4661 % 360; // 341

//Which quadrant does this land in? We'll assume that quadrant 1 starts from 0 and spans the first segment (72 degrees) in a clockwise manner and proceed accordingly.
var quadrantCount = 5;
var quadrant = Math.floor( deg / ( 360 / quadrantCount) ); // 4th index = last quadrant

//This puts us in quadrant 5. As we know this spans 288 degrees through less than 360 degrees and that deg equals 341, this is the correct answer.
```